# doxygen markdown change background color of fenced code blocks

Tags: markdown, doxygen

I have included a [fenced code block](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html#md_fenced) in my markdown file. In my document, I want to show some snippets showing the "right" and the "wrong" way to write code. It would be nice to visually represent the "right" and "wrong" snippets with different backgrounds.

Is there a way (other than manually editing the output HTML) to change the background color of the fenced code block?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the CSS that Doxygen uses to change the background colour for the fenced blocks, but I have failed to find a way to have two different colours in the way you are hoping.

You can generate a duplicate of the CSS doxygen uses using

```
doxygen -w html head.html foot.html css.css doxyfile
```

This gives you a CSS file to play with. You can ignore/delete the footer/header files. In the CSS the relevant class is `div.fragment` (circa line 180 in the 1.8.5 doxygen CSS).  Changing the `background-color` here changes the background colour for a fenced code block.

You'll need to point the doxyfile `HTML_STYLESHEET` setting to point at your modified CSS.

Given that all fenced blocks processed by doxygen will presumably use the same CSS class, I doubt that what you are looking to do is possible by trivial configuration changes.

Caveat :) I've found this by experiment because I want something similar, but I doubt we can categorically say doxygen will continue to use this class name for this purpose in the future.

Comment: Note: Don't use the HTML_STYLESHEET but try to add the HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET